# Jersey numbers in NCAA basketball

Tags: rules, equipment, basketball, collegiate, uniform

I noticed that jersey numbers in NCAA basketball are confined between 0-5 <sub>(for both digits)</sub>. There seem to be no jerseys with numbers between 6-9 <sub>(for both digits)</sub>. I can imagine [the practice of retiring numbers becoming a problem](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/has-the-practice-of-retiring-numbers-ever-become-a-problem) if this is the case.

Why do NCAA basketball jerseys only use numbers that are 0-5, 10-15, 20-25, 30-35, 40-45, 50-55, or am I wrong? Is there a rule that defines such? If so, why was this rule implemented?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a rule about this. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_%28sports%29#Basketball):

> American basketball leagues at all levels traditionally use single and double digits between 0 and 5 (i.e. 0, 00, 1–5, 10–15, 20–25, 30–35, 40–45, and 50–55). The NCAA and most amateur competitions mandate that only these numbers be used. This eases non-verbal communication between referees, who use fingers to denote a player's number, and the official scorer. In college basketball, single-digit players' numbers are officially recorded as having a leading zero. Teams can have either a "0" or "00", but they cannot have both.

Basically, it eases the communication between the refs and the scorers; since you only have five fingers per hand, refs can only denote numbers one through five non-verbally. After a foul, if you watch the ref you'll notice that they show the scorers which player it was by showing their jersey number with their hands.

**Edit:**

This can be found [here](http://www.usabasketball.com/rules/rules.html) at the bottom of the grid. In the [NCAA pdf on basketball rules](http://www.ncaapublications.com/productdownloads/BR13.pdf), Rule 3, Article 5.b.2 the useable numbers are shown (this is on page 41 in the link):

> The following numbers are legal: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 00, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
>   15, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, and 55. Team rosters can include 0 or 00, but not
>   both.